# Reusing same context Menu for multiple idMso

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

In my case the context menu is same when user click on the Mail Item or Mail file attachment.

[image]

Is there a common idMso event which can replace both ContextMenuAttachments & ContextMenuMailItem.?

If not, then as you can see I have to duplicate the menus to handle two different idmso even though the underlying click event function is same. Is there a better way to avoid this menu duplication.